# Error building x64 Windows Store App

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I haven't found this error anywhere else. Can't figure out what is causing this and can't get rid of it.

```
Could not run the "GetSdkToolFullPath" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run.
The "GetSdkToolFullPath" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "ActualToolFullPath" parameter. Object does not match target type.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Base questions out of the way: You're running 64-bit Windows, correct? And have the x64 sdk installed? Have you tried finding out 'SdkToolFullPath' and seeing if it exists? You may have to follow through the `.targets` files to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating Visual studio (Tools>Extensions and Updates...>Updates)? I was having this problem, and updating fixed it for me.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem.
I installed a beta version of the new Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, but then uninstalled. The uninstallation seems to have been the problem. But with the beta version of that SDK there are some other bugs that are a worse problem for me than this.

Comment: Oh. Have you tried a complete uninstall/reinstall of Visual Studio? If not, it may be your only option. VS can be really bad at removing updates.

Comment: I already did that several times with no visible results :(
It seems to be a deeper problem. Maybe it has to do with the .NET Framework.